# Read and import a .PLY flle with C#

Tags: c#, file, import

Hi i would to like to know if is any way to read a .ply file and take only X-Y-Z positions.A ply file format is:

```
ply

format ascii 1.0

element vertex 303943

property float x

property float y

property float z

property uchar red

property uchar green

property uchar blue

end_header

1.955 1.647 -1.359 182 185 182 

0.87 1.532 -1.453 152 160 153 

0.843 1.548 -1.484 153 161 154 

0.832 1.539 -1.472 151 159 152
```

I haven't find anything yet except a method to do that at Matlab.

Comment: What's stopping you from writing some c# code to parse this format and get x,y and z ?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the concept of StackOverflow. You don't describe what you want and people send you code. You provide a [mcve] of your own code and tell us what isn't working. If you are looking for an existing library to do that for you - that's off-topic here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication93
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<double>> data = new List<List<double>>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputLine = "";
            Boolean endHeader = false;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    if(endHeader)
                    {
                        List<double> newRow = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
                        data.Add(newRow);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(inputLine.Contains("end_header"))
                        {
                            endHeader = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: note, that script will read also the 'Face List'.. if you just want the vertices, should read the vertex count from PLY header and read only that amount of lines. (or stop reading when inputLine.Split gives more than 3 values.
ply format:
http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/